# Unable to move entire div to center of the page

Tags: html, css

iam new to web development, iam trying to move entire div to center of the page. But iam unable to do this, also not getting any error.
Below is the code of the html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<style>
#chart {
width:500px;
height:450px;
background-color:white;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    behavior: url(PIE/PIE.htc);
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Here goes some tilte</title>
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Determine your ring size in different countries.">
<meta name="KEYWORDS"
content="ring, size, USA, american, german, french, british, japanese, swiss">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
function changeValues(which) {
  document.countries.D1.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D2.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D3.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D4.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D5.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D6.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D7.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D8.selectedIndex = which;
  document.countries.D9.selectedIndex = which;
}
// --></script>

<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print">

<script language="JavaScript" src="/misc_functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="pink">
<div  align="center" id="chart" >
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="450">
<tr>
<td width="470" valign="top" class="content">
<div align="center">
<span class="red"><font color="Black"><h3>Here will be having a static data on the form<h3></font></span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Place main data here -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="/browser_detection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>
<blockquote>
<p><font size="3" color="#FF0000"><b>You do not have JavaScript enabled.</b></font><br>
<font size="2" color="#000080">The conversions on this site require the use of JavaScript so please enable before continuing.
For assistance in enabling JavaScript, please contact the webmaster.</font></p>
</blockquote>
</noscript>
    <form method="POST" name="countries">
<div align="center">
<table border="0" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0)">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">USA </td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5FF">INDIA</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5FF">PAKISTAN</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5FF">CHINA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"><select name="D1" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D1.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
<option>Damodar</option>
      </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5FF"><select name="D2" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D2.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
      </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5FF"><select name="D3" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D3.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
      </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D5D5FF"><select name="D4" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D4.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
     </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div align="center">
<table border="0" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0)">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">British</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">French</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">German</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">Japanese</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF">Swiss</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"><select name="D5" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D5.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
     </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"><select name="D6" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D6.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
     </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"><select name="D7" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D7.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
      </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"><select name="D8" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D8.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
      </select></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#DFDFDF"><select name="D9" size="1"
    onChange="changeValues(document.countries.D9.selectedIndex);">
      <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;---</option>
      <option>Damodar</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
      </div>
      </center>
    </form>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p align="center"><font color="#800000">Here will be having a static data on the form</font></p>
    <p><font color="#000080"><big>Here will be having a static data on the form</big></font><ol>
      <li><font color="#004080">Here will be having a static data on the form</font></li>
      <li><font color="#004080">Here will be having a static data on the form</font></li>
    </ol></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
<table>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below iam attaching the screenshot, in that you can find the curvedbox, it is left to the page, i want that curved box and the under that elements to center.
Please can any one suggest how to do it

[image]

Comment: `align="center"` and your other inline styles are deprecated. Look into some [basic CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS) and consider separating style and content.

Comment: What's with all the "iam" instead of "I am"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#chart {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Use margin to center things.

Comment: Frankly, your use of deprecated inline styles (`align: center`, etc) is going to make helping you very difficult. Here is a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zEj/)—learn from it. `margin: auto` is how you center blocks. It's up to you to dig through your code—make sure your inline styles aren't overriding anything—and apply this to the relevant element.

Comment: Thanks, When i removed the inline style, then its working fine

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#chart {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="chart" >    //remove align
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed that div within a table. So you need to do few things.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="450">
<tr>
<td width="470" valign="top" class="content">
<div align="center">
<span class="red"><font color="Black"><h3>Here will be having a static data on the form<h3></font></span>
```

Change the table with to 100%
Center the alignment of td which holds div and width to 100%

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100%" valign="top" class="content" style="text-align:center;">
<div align="center">
```